# How can a width of 100% be achieved with responsive flexboxes?

Tags: css, responsive-design, flexbox

I want to achieve the following: a two-column layout. The first column contains text, the second column e.g. Input fields. The total space available in the second column should be used by the input fields, minus the first column.

When falling below a certain window width, the second column should be placed below the first.

Unfortunately, after a break, only 80% of the width is used by the input field. How can you ensure that the entire width is used by the input field after a break?

I don't want to use libraries and, if possible, Javascript.

I linked my experiment here.

https://codepen.io/ekadagami/pen/ExPayBR

This is the css code I use

```css
.flex-container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

div > div:nth-child(odd) {
  flex: 1 0 20%;
  max-width: 200px;
  min-width: 100px;
  background: lightgreen;
}

div > div:nth-child(even) {
  flex: 0 1 80%;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div>one bit of text</div>
    <div><input style="width:100%;" /></div>
    <div>tiny text</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" /></div>
    <div>a little bit more text</div>
    <div><input style="width:100%;" /></div>
    <div>even more text</div>
    <div><textarea style="width:100%;">hello world</textarea></div>
</div>
```

Comment: why not `flex:1 1 80%;` for inputs? they need to grow to fill all the width

Comment: @TemaniAfif: Sometimes life can be so easy. Thank you. Worked.